# IndexError: list index out of range on python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have the below Python code:

```
carFile = open("cars.txt", "r")

file_data = carFile.read()

carFile.close()

car_details_name = file_data.split("\n")[0].split("-")
car_details = file_data.split("\n")[1:]

cars = []

no_of_cars = len(car_details)

for i in range(no_of_cars):
    car = dict()
    for j, detail in enumerate(car_details_name):
        car[detail] = car_details[i].split("-")[j]
    
    car["car_price"] = str(int(car["selling_price"]) - int(car["discount"]) + int(car["tax"]))
    
    car["car_type"] = "LUXURY" if int(car["car_price"])>=8000 else "CONVENIENCE"
    
    cars.append(car)

car_details_name.append('car_price')
car_details_name.append('car_type')
    
for i in range(no_of_cars):    
    print(cars[i])
    print("\n")
    
processedCarFile = open("processedcars.txt", "w")
luxuryCarFile = open("luxurycars.txt", "w")
convenienceCarFile = open("conveniencecars.txt", "w")

processedCarFile.write(" - ".join(car_details_name) + "\n")
luxuryCarFile.write(" - ".join(car_details_name) + "\n")
convenienceCarFile.write(" - ".join(car_details_name) + "\n")

for car in cars:
    processedCarFile.write(" - ".join(list(car.values())) + "\n")
    
    if car["car_type"]=="LUXURY":
        luxuryCarFile.write(" - ".join(list(car.values())) + "\n")
    else:
        convenienceCarFile.write(" - ".join(list(car.values())) + "\n")
        
processedCarFile.close()
luxuryCarFile.close()
convenienceCarFile.close()
```

and here is the cars.txt content

```
car_model_number-car_manufacturer-tax-selling_price-discount
15AB83FUFBFU8-Maruti Suzuki-1000-7000-500
54GDG8FHNJVFV-Tata-800-7200-800
FRF84R99NKFNF-Mahindra-1000-8000-1200
HFD748BF4FJBF-Hyundai-750-11000-1750
```

I got below error :

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 17
     15 car = dict()
     16 for j, detail in enumerate(car_details_name):
---> 17     car[detail] = car_details[i].split("-")[j]
     19 car["car_price"] = str(int(car["selling_price"]) - int(car["discount"]) + int(car["tax"]))
     21 car["car_type"] = "LUXURY" if int(car["car_price"])>=8000 else "CONVENIENCE"


IndexError: list index out of range
```

can anyone help me how to fix this?

Comment: Hi, put a breakpoint in line 17 and check values of `i` and `j` when error occurs. One of indexes of `i` or `j` in car_details is not in `car_details list`.

Comment: Just an aside... Have you considered using the *csv* module for this?

Comment: no i don't need to use , txt file is required

Comment: Required? Why? Your data are in CSV format. If you're writing Python code (or indeed any other language) you should use modules/libraries that are available by default wherever possible. After all, why do you think so much effort was put into making modules like *csv* available?

Answer (score 0):

This demonstrates how, by using appropriate standard modules, it's easy to handle data such as that shown in the question.

The handling of the 3 output files is not shown here as OP's intent in that respect is unclear.

```
from csv import DictReader

FILENAME = 'cars.txt'
LUXURY_PRICE = 8_000

with open(FILENAME, newline='') as car_data:
    carlist = []
    for d in DictReader(car_data, delimiter='-'):
        price = int(d['tax']) + int(d['selling_price']) - int(d['discount'])
        d['car_price'] = price
        d['car_type'] = 'LUXURY' if price >= LUXURY_PRICE else 'CONVENIENCE'
        carlist.append(d)
    print(*carlist, sep='\n')
```

**Output:**

```
{'car_model_number': '15AB83FUFBFU8', 'car_manufacturer': 'Maruti Suzuki', 'tax': '1000', 'selling_price': '7000', 'discount': '500', 'car_price': 7500, 'car_type': 'CONVENIENCE'}
{'car_model_number': '54GDG8FHNJVFV', 'car_manufacturer': 'Tata', 'tax': '800', 'selling_price': '7200', 'discount': '800', 'car_price': 7200, 'car_type': 'CONVENIENCE'}
{'car_model_number': 'FRF84R99NKFNF', 'car_manufacturer': 'Mahindra', 'tax': '1000', 'selling_price': '8000', 'discount': '1200', 'car_price': 7800, 'car_type': 'CONVENIENCE'}
{'car_model_number': 'HFD748BF4FJBF', 'car_manufacturer': 'Hyundai', 'tax': '750', 'selling_price': '11000', 'discount': '1750', 'car_price': 10000, 'car_type': 'LUXURY'}
```